# Trying to understand some terminology

Tags: linear-algebra

When discussing in class an algorithm, teacher said that this algorithm, let us call it X, costs $k$ vector-product multiplications, $n^2/2 + O(n)$ and the same number of saxpy's.

Question: What is the meaning of $O(n)$ and saxpy's???

Comment: Short version: $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is the class of functions which behave asymptotically similiar to $f(n)=n$. You would say that a function  is in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ if it does not grow much faster than $n$. Examples would be $2n, 14n,\ldots$. Refer to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more detailed information about Big O notation.

Comment: and Saxpy (single-precision $AX+Y$) you can google. See e.g. http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/six-ways-saxpy/